# default scoping confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-2

UPDATED: 
I am setting default scope for some models in a runtime which seems working locally in my development env and my code is given below.

```
SET_OF_MODELS = [Event, Group, User]
```

```
@account = Account.find_by_subdomain(account_subdomain)
SET_OF_MODELS.each { |m| m.set_default_scope(@account.id) }
```

```
def set_default_scope(account_id)
 default_scope :conditions=> { :account_id => account_id }
end
```

If I execute this code in ruby console with say @account1, `User.first` returns @account1 user whereas if I repeat the code with @account2 then `User.first` returns @account1 user instead of @account2. And this problem is not revealed while running app in local server but in staging server.

My guess is towards their states if they are really cached but not sure. Can someone explain in depth.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you use the more conventional way, using @account.user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the above code but the problem was with the server used i.e. thin server. It worked perfectly after replacing thin with mongrel. I think `thin` wasn't allowing to execute set_default_scope more than once except after loading the application.

Answer (score 1):

`default_scope` will save state in its class. It's harmful in concurrent environment because it leads to race condition. So you must isolate scope state between requests.

You can use `around_filter`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  around_filter :set_default_scope
  def set_default_scope
    @account = Account.find_by_subdomain(account_subdomain)
    opts = :condition => {:account_id => @account.id}
    Event.send(:with_scope, opts) do 
      Group.send(:with_scope, opts) do 
        User.send(:with_scope, opts) do
          yield
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You can refactor `.send(:with_scope, opts)` to a class method like `with_account_scope(account_id)`

Comment: Thanks for your effort @ShiningRay. I am still not sure about the bug as you said which could be but above code works in my development and production environment but not in staging env. :(

Answer (score 1):

Development differs from production. In production all classes are loaded once and cached, so you can't redefine the default scopes on each request.
In development the classes are loaded on each request, to allow easy development: each change you do in the code is visible/active on the next request.

If you really want to, you can disable this behaviour in production. This will make your complete site slower, but maybe that is not really an issue. To turn this off, you have edit your `config/environments/production.rb`, find the line containing

```
config.cache_classes = true
```

and switch that to `false`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @nathanvda, but redefining default scope is working in development and production but not in staging and this is really weird since `cache_classes` is set true in production.rb Any suggestion on this?

Comment: Did you try setting it to `false`?

Comment: No I haven't tried that yet but I assume setting false in staging will solve my staging problem but how redefining default scope is working in production with `cache_classes` true?

Comment: Does your staging use `production.rb` or does it use a different file? I have no explanation why it should work. It seems logical that if classes are cached and only loaded once, it would not work. So I have no explanation why it could work in your production.